# function inside .each() gets called only once

Tags: jquery, function, loops, each

I have this code:

```
function paramsFormValidate()
{
    isFormValid = true;
    var counter = 0;
    $('.par-item input[type="number"]').each(function() {
        isFormValid = isFormValid && validateParameter( $(this) );
        counter++;
    });
    console.log(counter);
    return isFormValid;
}
```

It's for a custom validation I had to build. Problem is, the `validateParameter()` function should be called for every input element, but instead is getting called only once.

I've included a `counter` variable for debugging purpose (and even logged `$(this)` inside the `each` loop), but loop seems fine. Still `validateParameter()` will get called only for the first element of the loop.

The `validateParameter()` function doesn't involve ajax calls, it's just a bunch of assignments and if/else statements. In fact, I even tried deleting the whole function body and using this instead:

```
function validateParameter()
{
    console.log('meh');
    return false;
}
```

But of course it would log only one 'meh'.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ValerioBulla: If you want to run the validation method against each eleemnt regardless but also want to be able to indicate if any validation has failed on the form you need to change the loop ever so slightly to always execute the method and if `false` is returned record only that. I have added an implementation example of that to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Logical AND(&&)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) returns `isFormValid` if it can be converted to false; otherwise it returns `validateParameter($(this))`.

The first time you loop around `isFormValid` is `true`, hence `validateParameter($(this))` is executed and the result returned. In this case `false` which is assigned to `isFormValid`.

Any consecutive time the loop executes `isFormValid` is `false`, hence it is immidiatly used and `validateParameter($(this))` is not executed again.

---

To quote from the linked documentation:

> **Operator**
>   Logical AND (&&)
>
> **Usage**
>   expr1 && expr2
>
> **Description**
>   Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, &&
>   returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

**Edit**

> ..the `validateParameter()` function should be called for every input
>   element

In that case you need something similar to this:

```
function paramsFormValidate() {
    isFormValid = true;

    $('.par-item input[type="number"]').each(function () {
        // Validate each element...
        if(!validateParameter($(this)){
           // validation has failed on an element, indicate the form is invalid
           isFormValid = false;
        }

        // optionally, continue or exit if isformIsValid === false
    });

    return isFormValid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great info. I didn't know it would stop evaluating if the first operand is false. I've updated my function and now it works just fine. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because you are resetting isFormValid value to false ( "return false;" in `validateParameter`)

`isFormValid && validateParameter( $(this) );` `validateParameter` will only execute if isFormValid true.

Answer (score 0):

Your validateParameter function is returning false.

```
isFormValid = isFormValid && validateParameter( $(this) );
```

after the first pass, isFormValid becomes false (first time, it is true & validateParameter => which results in false and stores it in isFormValid)

in the second pass

```
isFormValid = isFormValid && validateParameter( $(this) );
```

will not call validateParameter because isFormValid is already false and the evaluation will not evaluate validateParameter.

That is the problem. return true from validateParameter and you will see this working the way you expect it.

Cheers!
Suj